# 'Programming by Coincidence' Excercise: Java File Writer

Tags: java, file-io

I just read the article [Programming by Coincidence](http://www.pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence). At the end of the page there are excercises. A few code fragments that are cases of "programming by coincidence". But I cant figure out the error in this piece:

> This code comes from a general-purpose
>   Java tracing suite. The function
>   writes a string to a log file. It
>   passes its unit test, but fails when
>   one of the Web developers uses it.
>   What coincidence does it rely on?

```
  public static void debug(String s) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("debug.log", true);
    fw.write(s);
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
  }
```

What is wrong about this?

Comment: Isnt it the case that unit tests does not guarantee a 100% fool-proofness? I mean, there are lots and lots of such coincidences we developers are facing since we started programming :)

Comment: @Bragaadeesh: This is a bad unit test because it violates the ["single responsibility principle"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). If you are testing if the method correctly logs the string, you should take the file I/O out of it. It should receive a `java.io.Writer` created from elsewhere and write to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code relies on the fact that there is a file called `debug.log` that is writable in the application's executing directory.  Most likely the web developer's application is not set up with this file and the method fails when he tries to use it.

A unit test of this code will work because the original developer had the right file in the right place (and with the right permissions).  This is the coincidence that allowed the unit test to succeed.

Comment: Yep, I was going to say something about permissions.

Comment: This makes sense indeed. Thanks for clarifying this!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting tidbit. Ideally, resources must be pulled from the classpath. However, there is no end to human studpidity though. What would happen if the file was present in test environment's classpath (say eclipse), but was missing in production deployments.?

Comment: Resources (if you mean files, in the context of this question) need not necessarily be pulled form classpath. The program doesn't have to know what classpath is. Classpath is used only by class loader. Java doesn't specify a "working directory" for file IO. It is the responsibility of the programmer to pass a working directory via a command line argument or ideally a system parameter and use it in the program.

Comment: That's what I meant by ideally. That would be easy for migration across platform, rather than hardcoding it.